# How to find changing date format from a string

Tags: regex, date

I need to get a date from a string 
when I use this :  `Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");`

I can find dates like : 09/25/2020 or 01/28/2019
But some times I get these dates: 1/2/2019 , 9/8/2018 and I can't get it from my string with my current regex, 
How can I solve this prob ?

Comment: Please check the limiting quantifiers syntax. All you need is to use `{min,max}` as per your requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you mean like that :Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"){2,1}

Comment: `\d{2}` matches two digits, `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits. Do not mix the C# code and the string regex pattern.